# Move an mail of a list of mail by the id

Tags: c#, list, email, move

I need to move a mail from a list of 5 mails that a class reads. This mail already has been processed by a logical that I created and has met the conditional created. The problem is that it moves those 5 emails and some do not meet the conditions. If the mail that has fulfilled the condition manages to enter the data into the database then it must be moved to the processed mail folder otherwise it must be moved to the error folder.

This is the class that gets the emails

```
    int bufferLength = 5;
    int indiceMail = 0;
    string from = "mail@gmail.com>";
    do
        {
            emailList.getEmails(bufferLength);
        while(indiceMail<emailList.emails.Count)
        {
            indiceMail++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reading: {0}", emailList.emails.Count);
    }while (emailList.MoreAvailable);
```

And this is the condition to move the mails

```
    string bodyMail = emailList.emails[indiceMail].body;
    match3 = Regex.Match(bodyMail, @"(?<=Status:) (\S+\b)");
    statuscompare = match3.Value;

    List<String> statusList = new List<string> { "i2", "i3", "i4", "i8" };
    bool ex = false;
    foreach (string item1 in statusList)
    {
        if (item1.Contains(statuscompare.Trim()))
        {
            ex = true;
            if (item1.Contains("i4"))
            {

                bool moveEmail = false;
                foreach (Email item in emailList.emails)
                {
                    if (emailList.emails[indiceMail].body.Contains("i4"))
                    {
                        // if (item.body.Contains(item1))
                        //{
                        moveEmail = true;
                        emailList.moveMail(item.id, emailList.config.PathSuccess);
                        break;
                        // }
                    }
                    if (moveEmail)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is part of a class to move the mails

```
        public void moveMail(string emailId, string folderPath)
        {
            string folderId = getMailFolderId(folderPath);
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, emailId);
            message.Move(folderId);
        }
```

Comment: This code will move the mail into the Error folder only the first email and only if that first email has the specific parameter value. Otherwise everything will go into the Success folder. You need to get rid of that _emailBool_ and just test the parameter value

Comment: The code move the 5 mails store in emailList.emails and I need move only the mail that has met the logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you process an email with error, you set the flag 'emailbool' to false, which moves every other email to the PathSuccess. Not sure how emailbool actually serves any purpose other than making sure only one email from all goes to error path.

```
foreach (Email item in emailList.emails)
{
    // This IF statement will either be true of false for ALL items.
    if (!Cmmd.Parameters["p_retorno"].Value.ToString().Equals("0")) 
    {
        emailList.moveMail(item.id, emailList.config.PathError);
    }
    else
    {
        emailList.moveMail(item.id, emailList.config.PathSuccess); 
    }
}
```

EDIT:
 For new code you posted, try this to move all emails that contain any string from statusList in its body.

```
    // This will move all emails that have one or more statusList in their body
    foreach (Email item in emailList.emails)
    {
        if (statusList.Where(x => item.body.Contains(x)).Count > 0)
        {
            emailList.moveMail(item.id, emailList.config.PathSuccess);
            break; // This statement will stop processing of any other emails.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm tried your solution but the problem is  that after moving that email, for example to the error folder, the foreach searches again for the other 4 items that are stored in emailList.emails.

Comment: what is Cmmd in your context?

Comment: Its the connection to the DB              using (OracleCommand Cmmd = new OracleCommand())

Comment: and how is it supposed to check against each item ? :)

Comment: The project searches for 5 in 5 (emailList.emails) in the inbox folder a specific sender and extracts a number from the subject, then in the body it looks for another number and if that number is classified then it must be entered into the DB, by means of a procedure. The return parameter indicates if the data has been entered into the DB, if it is 0 it was entered correctly, if it is 1 there was an error entering the data, and it will move to the errors folder.

Comment: the If Statement, ```if (!Cmmd.Parameters["p_retorno"].Value.ToString().Equals("0")``` has nothing to do with the item you are iterating over.

Comment: Yes was my mistake, I edited my post to clarify the context, the class moves the 5 emails and must to move the email that met with the conditional.